# Which is the most efficient way to find the limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(\arctan x-x)(1+3x)^{1/x}(\ln(1+\sqrt x))^3}{(e^{x^2}-1-x^2)\sqrt x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(\arctan x-x)(1+3x)^{1/x}(\ln(1+\sqrt x))^3}{(e^{x^2}-1-x^2)\sqrt x}$$
It looks like an indeterminate form (0/0) but applying L'Hôpital's rule would be too nasty, any recommendations?

Comment: how is the (1/x) part in the numerator defined to get 0/0?

Comment: Your numerator isn't clear.

Comment: judging by the superscripted parentheses I think he means $(1+3x)^{1/x}$ in the numerator and $e^{x^2}$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. [Taylor series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) is a powerful tool, one may insert
$$
\begin{align}
\arctan x &=x+\frac{x^3}3+O(x^5)
\\\ln(1+3x)&=3x-\frac{9x^2}2+O(x^3)
\\\left(\ln(1+\sqrt{x})\right)^3&=x^{3/2}-\frac{3 x^2}{2}+\frac{7 x^{5/2}}{4}+O(x^3)
\\e^{x^2}&=1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{2}+O(x^5)
\end{align}
$$ to get a numerator equal to 
$$
-\frac13 e^3 x^{9/2}+O(x^5)
$$ and a denominator equal to
$$
\frac{x^{9/2}}{2}+O(x^5)
$$ giving a limit equal to $$-\dfrac23\: e^3.$$

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: @BraveShine You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Given that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}(1+3x)^{1/x}=e^3,
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(\log(1+\sqrt{x}))^3}{\sqrt{x}^3}=1
$$
the limit reduces to
$$
e^3\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x(\arctan(x)-x)}{e^{x^2}-1-x^2}
$$
now applying De L'Hopital should be easier.